# HOMER findMotifsGenome.pl cannot find its sub.pl files

Tags: bash, perl, shell

Before I posting this, I read the previously post and checked the chr notation in my beds.

[HOMER de novo motif discovery cannot open hg19 fasta files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162494/homer-de-novo-motif-discovery-cannot-open-hg19-fasta-files)

I decided to use HOMER in order to find known motifs in a file. My file is in BED format. Since I have BED files and .pos files, I decided to use findMotifGenome.pl and I call it as it is in the manual. I got this output where I have empty output file. After I checked the possible problems; even though bed2pos.pl, checkPeakFile.pl cleanUpPeak.pl etc are located in the bin file, they cannot be located thus I got this error. I got the same results with giving either BED/.pos file. Could you help me out with this? Down below I shared the output of the program.

```
    Tuncs-MacBook-Pro:final_overlap morova$ perl ~/homer/bin/findMotifsGenome.pl deneme.pos hg19 motif/ -size 200 -len 8 

    Position file = deneme.pos
    Genome = hg19
    Output Directory = motif/
    Fragment size set to 200
    Motif length set at 8,
    Found mset for "human", will check against vertebrates motifs
sh: bed2pos.pl: command not found
sh: checkPeakFile.pl: command not found
sh: cleanUpPeakFile.pl: command not found
ls: /Users/morova/homer/.//data/genomes/hg19//preparsed//hg19.*.cgbins: No such file or directory
    Could not find background files for 200 bp fragments
    Below are the sizes that are already available prepared.
    HOMER will now create background files for 200 bp fragments
    To CANCEL and rerun with a differet "-size <#>", hit <CTRL+C> now!
        5
        4
        3
        2
        1
    Preparsing genome for 200 bp fragments...(will probably take 1-5 min)
sh: preparseGenome.pl: command not found
wc: /Users/morova/homer/.//data/genomes/hg19//preparsed//hg19.200.gcbins: open: No such file or directory
Use of uninitialized value $lineCount in numeric lt (<) at /Users/morova/homer/bin/findMotifsGenome.pl line 640.
!!!! Might have something wrong with preparsed files
!!!! Rerun and add "-preparse" to the command line to force recreation of the files
sh: resizePosFile.pl: command not found
sh: homerTools: command not found
sh: cleanUpSequences.pl: command not found
sh: removePoorSeq.pl: command not found

    Not removing redundant sequences

sh: homerTools: command not found
sh: freq2group.pl: command not found

    Total sequences set to 50000

    Choosing background that matches in CpG/GC Content...
wc: /Users/morova/homer/.//data/genomes/hg19//preparsed//hg19.200.gcbins: open: No such file or directory
cat: /Users/morova/homer/.//data/genomes/hg19//preparsed//hg19.200.gcbins: No such file or directory
sh: makeBinaryFile.pl: command not found
sh: randRemoveBackground.pl: command not found
sh: assignGeneWeights.pl: command not found
    Assembling sequence file...
sh: filterListBy.pl: command not found
    Normalizing lower order oligos using homer2
sh: homer2: command not found
    Finished preparing sequence/group files

    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Known motif enrichment
sh: findKnownMotifs.pl: command not found
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    De novo motif finding (HOMER)
sh: homer2: command not found
cat: motif//homerMotifs.motifs*: No such file or directory

 sh: compareMotifs.pl: command not found    Job finished - if results
 look good, please send beer to ..

    Cleaning up tmp files...
```

I checked those perl scripts if they are located in bin folder. Yes they do locate at that spesific place. Is there a way to get around ?

Comment: Looks like the tool expects to be run from the directory with the other tools. Try `cd ~/homer/bin/; ./findMotifsGenome.pl /path/to/deneme.pos hg19 motif/ -size 200 -len 8` or similar.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ohh did you mean, instead of calling the tool from files directory, vice versa?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming that if you look in `findMotifsGenome.pl` you'll see it trying to call the other scripts as `./resizePosFile.pl` or similar.

Comment: dear @EtanReisner, i did like you said but still I got the same output ?here is my code. I also wanted to mention that I am in the same bin folder which contains all the .pl scripts. Also, i tried several of the codes to work individually. then they worked fine.        Tuncs-MacBook-Pro:bin morova$ perl findMotifsGenome.pl /Volumes/MyPassport/LackLab/GSE70079_RAW/GSE70090beds/deneme/bedfiles/final_overlap/deneme.pos hg19 /Volumes/MyPassport/LackLab/GSE70079_RAW/GSE70090beds/deneme/bedfiles/final_overlap/motif/ -size 200 -len 8

Comment: Same exact errors? It might be trying to run the tools as just `$toolname` and so might expect that you put its `bin/` path into your `$PATH` variable.  You should probably ask the Homer people about this and suggest that they make this less annoying to get working (and/or at least document this requirement specifically).

Comment: Ah and, in fact, they **do** specifically tell you to add the Homer `bin/` directory to your `$PATH` variable in [the documentation](http://homer.salk.edu/homer/introduction/install.html) in the "Installing the basic HOMER software" section.

Comment: O MAI GODDDDDDDDD @EtanReisner it worked it worked!!!! thank you very much for your help my friend. I owe you very big one !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the location of the HOMER executables to the PATH variable on your bashrc file:  PATH=$PATH:/XXX/XXXX/HOMER/bin

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, add the homer/bin directory to your executable path(~/.bash_profile file). two steps: 
(1) vim ~/.bash_profile (add a line) 
(2) source ~/.bash_profile

you can check install instruction in official url: http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/introduction/install.html [Installing the basic HOMER software]